# Security in unofficial telegram apps(that use Telegram API)

Tags: api, file-access, telegram

I was wondering that can developers of an unofficial [Telegram apps](https://telegram.org/) gain access to media and files that users send over the app? (Unofficial Telegrams use the Telegram API and connect to Telegram servers).

Comment: Sorry, that comes across a little garbled. Are you asking whether an app that uses the Telegram API can get access to media that is shared?

Comment: Yes, in fact I wanna know if I use the unofficial telegram, whether the developers of this app can access to my messages and media?

Answer (score 3):

Developers of any application can get hold of the data that passes through the application *if* they can find a way to transfer the information without you objecting.

This has been demonstrated time and again on all of the mobile platforms app stores with apps transferring data out.

With Telegram, as with any secure comms app, the security is really only in-transit (point-a to point-b). Once data is inside the app, the app can by definition do stuff with it, in general the data cannot remain encrypted within the app.

Cautious or paranoid users will monitor applications for unexpected network activity that might indicate data leaving their machine without permission. This is particularly hard to do on a mobile device due to the app limitations normally applied.

Comment: "if they can find a way to transfer the information without you objecting." I am confused now. With limitations in telegram API, is there a way for developers of unofficial telegrams to see my sent messages over the app and access to every files I have in the app?

Comment: It isn't the API that's the issue but rather the mobile app platforms. You might want to read up on mobile platform security issues. Telegram itself seems fairly secure though I've not seen a rigorous analysis of it - certainly it is being used as though it is secure. But all of the mobile platforms have app vulnerabilities.